# Getting myself removed from the SORBS blacklist

Tags: email-server, blacklist

I am now on the SORBS-SPAM blacklist, how can I get myself removed?

This was an issue originally with another machine in our company which has since been cleaned up, but I think because I share the same domain name I am being blocked.

Comment: Seriously? They have a delisting link right on their home page.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the blacklisting site in question and see if there's a link with instructions how to get removed. Most do have some instructions, but don't think they'll be friendly about it...they routinely deal with spammers and angry people, so you'll have to work extra hard to keep your patience level high and be as understanding as possible.

Being friendly (if their procedure isn't automated, which it may be) if you find that you're dealing with a human at some point can get you further than losing your patience with them.

Comment: They all should have instructions on getting off of the spam list, though you should clean up your spam-related issues (and it sounds like you have) and they should be very friendly if you explain what was wrong before and the steps you took to clean it up. Worked well for us on CBL!